# Why perpendicular axis are unaffected in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In SR why are $y=y'$ and $z=z'$?
I understand the examples they give to show physical contradictions if this was not the case, but it seems highly unsatisfactory as there is no physical basis for this assumption ($y=y'$) stemming either from the math or postulates of SR. An analogy to this would be the application of Bernoulli's theorem to a system of pipe that gets thinner as we move along it, but water density remains constant. Thus we say that velocity in that region increases to maintain density, however again this is unsatisfactory since we are just making conclusions based on what will happen if our conclusion weren't true and how it will affect our assumptions (constant density in this case), instead of looking at the physics of the situation as done in this video: https://youtu.be/TcMgkU3pFBY

Comment: There is a good book that discusses this. See Rindler's Relativity, Special, General and cosmological

Comment: This situation also holds for Galilean relativity. By the way, in ordinary Euclidean geometry, rotation of the xy-plane leaves the z-axis invariant. (That is to say, a question like this for special relativity should also be directed to Galilean relativity and Euclidean geometry.)

Answer (score 1):

> there is no physical basis for this assumption (y=y') stemming either from the math or postulates of SR

This is incorrect. In fact, that $y=y’$ stems directly from the first postulate, often called the principle of relativity.

In [Nothing But Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045) Pal derives the most general inertial transformations that are compatible with principle of relativity. They show that assuming only that principle leads to only two admissible transformations: the Galilean transform and the Lorentz transform. Both of which have $y=y’$.

Answer (score 0):

A non rigorous way of seeing that the perpendicular axes should be unaffected is to consider that the magnitude of the effects of SR are speed-dependent and must vanish at low speeds to account for our everyday experience of space and motion. Given that the magnitude of the effects is zero for zero speed, then it is reasonable to suppose that the effects must be zero in any direction in which the component of speed is zero.

However, that is not a proof by any means, but you can figure it out on a more solid basis if you consider that the speed of light is the same in all directions for all observers. From that principle you can show that planes of simultaneity are tilted in the direction of motion, thus the other relativistic effects of time dilation and length contraction (which follow from the relativity of simultaneity) are zero perpendicular to the direction of relative motion.